# how to change data in datagridview using group of comboboxes selection

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a Windows form application where i would print a fee Receipt for a student
But for this i would require to select different fee structures tables from the database
I have four different categories

1)Stream com or sci - 2

2)type of course aided or unaided 2

3)course- 3 courses -3

4)Year - FY/ SY - 2

So these are the combobox values and  by selecting from each and every combobox to get one final value like 
SCi - aided - Course - Fy Combination (example )
MY Question is how should i use the datagridview so that when i select those values i should be able to retrieve one table from   (2 X 2 X 3 X 2 )  tables by just selecting combobox values 
How should i connect all values in one and then retrieve the specified combination from the database in the datagridview so that i could print the same fee structure for the student !

Comment: Are you looking for SQL calls or datagridview help?

Comment: @ I didnt get your word SQL Call ? Although i am using SQL server 
in which my different table are stored to be retrieved in dgv

Comment: Are you looking for "Select * From Table" or "datagridview1.headersomething = 12"

Comment: @ZL1Corvette I am looking for datagridview values which are retrieved from values of combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done by designer mode in visual studio 2010 where you can easily drag and drop the datasource and set it a dynamic way